# Graphing Multivariables in R

Tags: r, variables, plot, graph, categorical-data

This is a data set for marriage rates within the U.S. from the 1990's until 2016. I want to be able to call variables such as State, Year, and Rate so that I can plot them against each other. However when I try to plot these axis it says not found or the length doesn't match. Here is what I have tried to do to fix the issue.

```
marriage<-read.csv(file="~/Desktop/datah.csv", header=T, 
sep=",",check.names=FALSE)
marriage
MARR=marriage$State
plot(MARR)
x=1:52
plot(x, MARR)
```

Data looks something like this

```
                  State 2017 2016 2015 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006 2005 2004 2003 2002 2001 2000
1               Alabama  7.0  7.1  7.4  7.8  7.8  8.2  8.4  8.2  8.3  8.6  8.9  9.2  9.2  9.4  9.6  9.9  9.4 10.1
2                Alaska  6.9  7.1  7.4  7.5  7.3  7.2  7.8  8.0  7.8  8.4  8.5  8.2  8.2  8.5  8.1  8.3  8.1  8.9
3               Arizona  5.8  5.9  5.9  5.8  5.4  5.6  5.7  5.9  5.6  6.0  6.4  6.5  6.6  6.7  6.5  6.7  7.6  7.5
4              Arkansas  9.5  9.9 10.0 10.1  9.8 10.9 10.4 10.8 10.7 10.6 12.0 12.4 12.9 13.4 13.4 14.3 14.3 15.4
5          California 1  6.3  6.5  6.2  6.4  6.5  6.0  5.8  5.8  5.8  6.7  6.2  6.3  6.4  6.4  6.1  6.2  6.5  5.8
6              Colorado  7.3  7.4  6.8  7.1  6.5  6.8  7.0  6.9  6.9  7.4  7.1  7.2  7.6  7.4  7.8    8  8.2  8.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean up your data first so it is long instead of wide:

```
library(tidyr)

# the `2017`:`2000` syntax grabs all the columns between those two,
# so you might need to change that to whichever the bookend years are
# in your actual data
mydata <- mydata %>%
    gather(key=year, value=rate, `2017`:`2000`)
```

Now you have long data you can plot rate against state by year or however you would like. E.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)

# if you are plotting many states at once, this is going to look cluttered
# so consider different ways to visualize them all together if that is
# the goal
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=year, y=rate, group=State)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=State)) +
    geom_line(aes(color=State)) +
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: you can use starts_with("20")